# Allowing PHP to run specific bash script with root permissions

Tags: php, permissions, bash, sudo, user-permissions

I have a php script calling a bash script like this:

```
<?php
    $result = exec('sudo /bin/bash /var/www/my_bash_script.sh /var/www/vhosts/testsite/htdocs/');
    var_dump($result);
?>
```

This is the contents of `my_bash_script.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn export --force --no-auth-cache --username myusername --password mypassword http://1.2.3.4/repos/path/to/repo/ $1 2>&1
find $1 -print0 -type d | xargs -0 -n 1 -0 chown -R -v root:root 2>&1
find $1'storage' -print0 -type d | xargs -0 -n 1 chown -R -v apache 2>&1
find $1'shared' -print0 -type d | xargs -0 -n 1 chown -R -v apache 2>&1
```

The purpose of the script is to do an export from my svn repo and set user permissions correctly.

PHP runs as the `apache` user.

In order to grant PHP permission to run this script I have added the following line to sudoers:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Now obviously this gives PHP too much power, so I want to restrict PHP to just run this specific bash script, but I can't seem to get the syntax right:

```
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/my_bash_script.sh
```

The above just returns an empty string (to the `$result` PHP variable) - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Edit:** - I have already commented out `#Defaults    requiretty` in sudoers.

Comment: Why does this need to run from a PHP script?

Comment: Unfortunately we have to make this feature client facing so it has to run from our web interface.

Comment: Can do it as better outlined here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/130906/why-does-setuid-not-work

Comment: Lets just hope that `storage` and `shared` dont symlink to `/` as that might have some pretty negative consequences.

Comment: @MatthewIfe They don't :)

Comment: Rather than having PHP execute sudo, I'd have a PHP script put the task into a queue, and have a cron script running as a privileged user monitor that queue and execute as needed. Would be significantly safer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be wrong, but I believe that sudoers also restricts parameters that can be passed to a command/script, not just the command itself.

If you try to run your .sh without the parameter it will likely work e.g.

```
  sudo /bin/bash /var/www/my_bash_script.sh
```

So, to tell sudoers to allow that script to be run with any parameters (by apache), you would need to adjust the line like so:

```
  apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/my_bash_script.sh *
```

The wildcard would allow apache to run that script with any parameters.

You may also need /bin/bash in that line but I'm not certain

```
  apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /var/www/my_bash_script.sh *
```

If anyone can confirm or refute my understanding of this it would be much appreciated

Comment: That did it!! I changed the line to: `apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/bash /var/www/cp_svn.sh *` Thanks for all your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following settings

```
Cmnd_Alias SVNUP = /root/webhooks/svn_update.sh
apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: SVNUP
```

Create simple test script

```
# cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

set -u
echo "Param1: $1"
```

Make simple tests

```
$ id alex
uid=506(alex) gid=506(alex) groups=506(alex)

$ cat /root/webhooks/test.sh
cat: /root/webhooks/test.sh: Permission denied

$ sudo /root/webhooks/test.sh val1
Param1: val1

$ sudo /root/webhooks/test.sh
/root/webhooks/test.sh: line 5: $1: unbound variable
```

But you must be a really careful due to variable expansions, for e.g.

```
$ sudo /root/webhooks/test.sh "$(rm -fr ~/*)"
```

P.S.
As alternative you can use mpm-itk with apache and run this particular vhosts with specific user.